# Curl callback raised only once when asking for list of files

Tags: file, curl, ftp

I'm looking to retrieve a list of file in a specific file of my ftp server with cURL, but I am face to a problem I don't understand.

Here is a sample of my code :

```
// In the init part of my code i call

CURLcode Code = CURL_LAST;

Code = curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
if (CURLE_OK == Code)
{
  mHandleCurl = curl_easy_init();
}

// ... and then the process part

curl_easy_reset (mHandleCurl);

Code = curl_easy_setopt(mHandleCurl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
Code = curl_easy_setopt(mHandleCurl, CURLOPT_URL, "ftp://192.168.1.174/application");
Code = curl_easy_setopt(mHandleCurl, CURLOPT_DIRLISTONLY, "NLST");
Code = curl_easy_setopt(mHandleCurl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void * )&FileList);
Code = curl_easy_setopt(mHandleCurl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, GetFileListCallback);
Code = curl_easy_setopt(mHandleCurl, CURLOPT_PORT, mPortnumber);
Code = curl_easy_setopt(mHandleCurl, CURLOPT_USERNAME, mUsername.String());
Code = curl_easy_setopt(mHandleCurl, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, mPassword.String());
Code = curl_easy_perform(mHandleCurl);
```

Where FileList is just an Array of String and my callback GetFileListCallback just recovering apContents data with filename to store in FileList:

```
size_t CFtp::GetFileListCallback(void *apContents, size_t aSize, size_t aNmemb, void *apUserp)
{
 ...
}
```

There is my question:

Why my callback is called only once, with the full list of file in the same apContents and not called for each file in the directory I am looking ?

I expected to get callback for each file : "file1.txt" "file2.txt" ...
But what I've got is 1 callback with : "file1.txtfile2.txtfile3..." (separate with \n\r like this file1.txt\n\rfile2)

I took this sample in code that usualy work on Linux and I am working on Windows 10, I don't know which version of curl was used but I'm using cUrl-7.67.0 compiled as release for VC8.

Is is possible that the cURL version or the fact that I'm using cURL on Windows may lead to differences in the way things work ?

Answer (score 0):

[`CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION`](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.html) is called with a chunk of data retrieved from the FTP data connection (a file download or a directory listing).

That chunk is defined to be at most `CURL_MAX_WRITE_SIZE` (with default of is 16KB).

So it is not called once per file. But neither with a full list (unless the whole list fits into one chunk).